# Matlab Instfreq Units

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

The matlab `instfreq` function automatically makes a plot using units of seconds and hertz, even though I have not specified units. Is there a way to prevent it from doing this conversion automatically?

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation:](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/instfreq.html)

- `instfreq(___)` with no output arguments plots the estimated instantaneous frequency.

but

- `ifq = instfreq(x,fs)` estimates the instantaneous frequency of a signal, `x`, sampled at a rate `fs`.
- `[ifq,t] = instfreq(___)` also returns `t`, a vector of sample times corresponding to `ifq`.

You should be able to use the output `t` to plot in whatever units float your boat!